# How can I GET from a Cloud Function from a Deployed Firebase App

Tags: javascript, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I currently have a Firebase App that works locally when I use localhost:5001 for calling the functions; however, when I try to use the cloud functions when directly routed I get ERROR: FORBIDDEN, and when I try to directly fetch from my deployed Firebase app I get a CORS error.

The front end calls a service, which fetches from the backend the data.

```
 const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };
 return fetch("https://us-central1-polling-269dc.cloudfunctions.net/api/polls/get", requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
```

I've also tried just not having the mode and headers on there, but it doesn't work. Fetch is correctly being called, but on the loading page of https://polling-269dc.firebaseapp.com/#/ I get this error message:

Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-polling-269dc.cloudfunctions.net/api/polls/get' from origin 'https://polling-269dc.firebaseapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

In my functions folder in my index.js, this is the function and prequisite imports:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fire = require("./fire.js");
var database = fire.database();
var auth = fire.auth();

app.get("api/polls/get/", (req, res) => {
  var ref = database.ref("polls/");
  var query = ref.orderByChild("question");
  var sum = [];
  query.once("value", (snap) => {
    snap.forEach( (childSnap)  => {
      sum.push(childSnap.val());
    });
    res.json(sum);
  });
});
```

I've also tried

```
app.get("https://us-central1-polling-269dc.cloudfunctions.net/api/polls/get/", (req, res) => {
```

Which has similar results. I suspect that I'm calling the wrong URL or I need to prepare something, but I can't find information about it.

Here's my firebase.json, is something wrong here perhaps?

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "client/build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "**",
      "function": "app"
    } ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

Again, this works when I use a localhost and use firebase serve, but I'm trying to figure it out for Firebase Deployment online. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out the issue; you need to add the name of the exported set of functions in the call. My call should've been:

```
https://us-central1-polling-269dc.cloudfunctions.net/app/api/polls/get
```

instead of

```
https://us-central1-polling-269dc.cloudfunctions.net/api/polls/get
```

I hope this helps anyone who was having a similar issue!